# while building mozilla DEBUG: mt: Trying mt.exe , ERROR: Cannot find mt, how to fix this?

Tags: firefox, visual-studio-2017

We are developing a new browser using opensource mozilla firefox , while building the project it is showing below

DEBUG: mt: Trying mt.exe ,  ERROR: Cannot find mt,

*** Fix above errors and then restart with\
                "c:/mozilla-build/mozmake/mozmake.EXE -f client.mk build"

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're having this problem because you're building on Windows 10, for this there is a workaround:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356493